# What is the django way of doing a subselect?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a versioned model which (simplified) looks a bit like:

```
Project(id, ref, version)

unique_together(ref, version)
```

Where id is the autogenerated primary key, ref is a random UUID and version is an integer incremented by my application. Each time I save the project I create a new instance, add 1 to the version and copy the ref to the new object.

The following SQL will give me back the latest version of every Project, by doing a subselect.

```
SELECT * FROM myapp_project WHERE (ref, version) IN
(SELECT ref, max(version) FROM myapp_project GROUP BY ref)
```

Alternatively (slightly simpler perhaps):

```
SELECT * from myapp_project p
WHERE p.version =
(SELECT max(version) FROM myapp_project p1 WHERE p1.ref = p.ref)
```

How do I achieve the same query using Django's ORM?

Edit: I've got as far as this -

```
foo = Project.objects.values('ref').annotate(version=Max('version'))
```

This gives me something that looks right if I inspect it. As soon as I try to get the id out with:

```
foo.values('id')
```

It seems to discard the original result and gives back all the rows.

Edit more:

Worked around it for now with .extra():

```
maxids = """id in (SELECT id from myapp_project p WHERE p.version = 
(SELECT max(version) FROM myapp_project p1 WHERE p1.ref = p.ref))"""

Project.objects.all().extra(where=[maxids])
```

Comment: offtopic: from the performance perspective, most of the queries will be to the latest version of the projects, so it make sense to change sligthly your approach and to have your latest versions marked somehow. There are few options, simplest one is to have None as the lastest version, so you can select all projects with null's as version to get the latest versions, version will be updated when new project version will be added, or add some flag 'latest' - in any case simple filter will give you list of latest versions - big gain on performance

Answer (score 2):

Using [in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#in)

here is an example straight from the linked document

```
inner_qs = Blog.objects.filter(name__contains='Cheddar')
entries = Entry.objects.filter(blog__in=inner_qs)
```

The exact query that you are using isn't one that is supported by all databases that work with Django. For example while it works on postgresql it does not work on sqlite so you would have to change your approach to use the primary key instead of the unique_together key. Or use a join.

`Update` the second query can be handled more easily but I will refrain from posting that here since that would seem like plagarizing @anand's answer.

Comment: How does that work when there are 2 fields in the IN clause?

Comment: @Darren you can pass a `queryset` in filter.

Answer (score 1):

You can build it like this:

```
from django.db.models import Max
latest_refs_with_max_id = Project.objects.values('ref').annotate(Max('version'), Max('id')).values('id__max')

latest_refs = [ d['id__max'] for d in latest_refs_with_max_id]

q = Project.objects.filter(id__in=latest_refs)
```

[image: Testing]

*Note: This will pick the max id, in case you have multiple records with same max `version` and `ref`*

Comment: The first line gives an error: FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'max' into field. Join on 'id' not permitted.

Comment: @Darren can you specify, which DB are you using for backend.

Comment: @Darren try this solution, it works for me on MySQL, I hope it works for you as well.

Comment: Thanks @anand, it looks promising but I don't think you can do filter with 2 lists like that - it doesn't line up the elements of the lists. The query it generates looks like 'version in (1,2,3) and ref in (4,5,6)' so it would bring back the wrong data.  I've worked around it for now using 'extra'.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this: First you fetch all the refs, and then you get the Project with the highest version for each ref:

```
projects = []
for ref in Project.objects.all().values_list('ref', flat=True).distinct():
    projects.append(Project.objects.filter(ref=ref).order_by('-version')[0])
```

More efficient version:

```
from django.db.models import Max
max_project_versions = Project.objects.values('ref').annotate(id_max=Max('version')).values_list('id_max', flat=True)
projects = Project.objects.filter(id__in=max_project_versions)
```

Comment: That would result in quite a lot of queries

Comment: It depends on the number of refs. If there are few refs and lots of projects per ref it would work perfectly.

Comment: The result needs to be a queryset.

Comment: That query gives the version numbers, not the id

Comment: What id do you need?